# PostgreSQL: How to avoid divide by zero?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, nullif

I am trying to get the average occupation rate from table occu_cap but I am getting the error "ERROR:  division by zero". There are 0 values in both columns.
I've been looking at using NULLIF(column_name,0) but I can't figure out how to implement this into the code below.

```
SELECT *, AVG((occupancy/capacity) * 100)) AS avg_occupancy_rate
FROM occu_cap
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Sample data and expected result:

| occupancy | capacity | avg_occupancy_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1232 | 1630 | 75.58 |
| 0 | 658 | null |
| 0 | 0 | null |

Comment: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=44f66ade118f754b25520f8e78a34f3f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was caused that `capacity` was `0` value (which might not allow from math divide), if your expected result is `0` when `capacity` is `0` from `occupancy/capacity`

```
AVG((COALESCE(occupancy / NULLIF(capacity,0), 0) * 100))
```

**Edit**

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression to judge the value whether zero then return `NULL`

```
AVG(CASE WHEN capacity <> 0 AND occupancy <> 0 THEN ((occupancy::decimal/capacity * 1.0) * 100) END)
```

If you want to show all of columns you can try to use the window function.

```
SELECT *,AVG(CASE WHEN capacity <> 0 AND occupancy <> 0 THEN ((occupancy::decimal/capacity * 1.0) * 100) END) OVER(PARTITION BY id)
FROM occu_cap
```

**NOTE**

If your `occupancy` or `capacity` is not a type of a float-point number we need to `CAST` that as a float-point number before doing `AVG`

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=86ab1c29d0319f3d9407d23cc9e76bbb)

Comment: Hi, when using your syntax the output is only 0.0000000 for every row.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expcet result? It worked in SQLfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b32c2cdbac9bcf2087c7321ec99d06e7